# What is IP address on a subnet

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, xen

I'm reading the requirements for a virtualized environment from [here](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-xen_draft/cha.xen.vhost.html#tab.xen.vhost) which says:

> IP Address
>
> ```
> - One IP address on a subnet for the host.
> - One IP address on a subnet for each VM Guest.
> ```

I want to know if a normal home network (router connected to the Internet) would meet this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Your home router will NAT so all IPs behind it are presented to the internet as coming from your ISP-allocated public IP.

Check the range (normally 192.168.x.y) that your router uses and create static IPs for the hosts on this range. (Not sure if you're using DHCP - I expect you are - in which case you'll want to add these static IPs as exclusions to the DHCP range so it doesn't try and allocate the same IPs to something else.)

Answer (score 2):

From the current system find out the IP address. (ifconfig -a in *nix and ipconfig /all on windows).

If your netmask to 255.255.255.0 (default class C mask) and IP address something like 192.168.1.xx, then you would need to decide one IP address in same range (here between 192.168.1.2 or 3 up to 192.168.1.254) for the host. Then each VM guest will need one IP in the same range.